# AngularJS ui-grid Exclude column from being able to select row when using enableFullRowSelection

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Is there a way to exclude a column from being able to select row? in the example below I would like to make the age column unable to select the row.

http://plnkr.co/edit/OFoJydRpzoKAGBw3Tfzw?p=preview

```
  $scope.gridOptions = { enableFullRowSelection: true, enableRowHeaderSelection: false };

  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { name: 'id' },
    { name: 'name'},
    { name: 'age', displayName: 'Age (not focusable)', allowCellFocus : false },
    { name: 'address.city' }
  ];

  $scope.gridOptions.multiSelect = false;
  $scope.gridOptions.modifierKeysToMultiSelect = false;
  $scope.gridOptions.noUnselect = true;
  $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function( gridApi ) {
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
       gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){
        var msg = 'row selected ' + row.isSelected;
        $scope.callMe(row.entity);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use custom cellTemplate where you can handle cell click in a custom way (ignore click, or deselect row immediately).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before, You need to use custom cell template and disable event propagation.
Following Your code, cell template should be:

```
cellTemplate: '<div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">{{row.entity.age}}</div>'
```

Please see this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/BsmtzMQ9nNyWcSVuZDu4?p=preview